# GoDaddy Shared Hosting block access to folder and contents but use the script within folder

Tags: xml, .htaccess, web-config

Hope this is easy to solve as it making me feel rather silly.

i have a .com hosted o a shared windows server, my root. in my root i have my index.php and a folder called "admin".

All i am trying to do is use my index.php to greet visitors and block anybody from accesing, posting to and linking to any thing within my admin folder, whilst allo
i have tried .htaccess in the "admin" with deny all and today i found out that GoDaddys windows server takes no notice of .htacces file and i have to use Web.config instead :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users ="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

is what i have tried in "admin" after readin topics on it plus somthing simpler in root

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache thing.  IIS does not use it.

Comment: If you want to use PHP and .htaccess and don't need anything Windows specific like MS SQL or ASP .NET you can move to a Linux hosting account and your .htaccess fill would be recognized: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1285/switching-your-hosting-account-operating-system

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to do a window password protect your Admin folder so anyone that tries to visit your /admin folder will be required to login.  I am not sure if godaddy have such feature, but I know other hosting company that does.